# I have a list and want to find the similar(not same) elements as a list of lists. I am using longest Common Subsequent distance measure thresh 0.2

Tags: python, nlp, similarity

I have a list of words ex words= ["client relationships","people management","collaborative teams","collaborative team","collaboration teams".......] I am measuring the similarity and trying to make a list of similar words and then making a list out of these lists.
The output that i am looking for looks like:
[["collaborative teams", "collaborative team","collaboration teams"]]

I am using the following code:

```
> words= ["client relationships","people management","collaborative
> teams","collaborative team","collaboration teams".......]
> list1=[]
> for i in range(0,len(words)):
>     for j in range(i+1,len(words)):
>         t=[]
>         v=metric_lcs(words[i],words[j])
>         if v<=0.2:
>             t.append(words[i])
>             t.append(words[j])
>             list.append(t)
```

The output that I get is :

```
[[collaborative teams,collaborative team],[collaborative teams,collaboration teams],[collaborative team,collaborative team]]
```

The output that I am looking for is:

```
[["collaborative teams", "collaborative team","collaboration teams"]]
```

Could anyone help me with a solution to this.

New code:

```
> for i in range(0,len(words)): 
>     t=[]
>     for j in range(i+1,len(words)):  
>         v=metric_lcs(words[i],words[j])
>         if v<=0.2:
>             t.append(words[i])
>             t.append(words[j])
>             t=set(t)
>             M=list(t)
>             list1.append(M)
> t=list1   
> t.sort()
> list(t for t in,_ in itertools.groupby(t))
```

Now the output looks like:

```
[[“ability deliver”, “ability develop”],[“ability deliver”, ”quality delivery”],[“ability drive”, “ability deliver”]]
```

But I want the output as:

```
[“ability deliver”, “ability develop”,“ability deliver”, ”quality delivery”,“ability drive”, “ability deliver”]
```

Comment: You are comparing each word only to the next word and initializing `t=[]` at the beginning of each iteration, therefore your lists only can have two elements at max. If you wanna compare each word to every other word you can use nested loops.

Comment: I have used nested loops, while typig it here I missed the inner loop. The output shown here is with nested loops.  I have edited the code please have a look.

Comment: You are initializing the `t` list inside the second loop, for your purpose you should do that outside of the second loop. Try moving `t=[]` to the line before the second loop. If you don't wanna have duplicated words in your list you can use a set for your `t` variable. Also, if you don't wanna add a word that has been added to a list already to be added to another list you can use a flag for each word.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I have made changes and updated the code in the question  initializing t out side the loop helped., but I still do not get the desired output.

Comment: Check if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your desired output you should have a list of flags in which you hold whether the word has already been added to another list or not. And then add them if not seen:

```
from strsimpy.metric_lcs import MetricLCS

metric_lcs = MetricLCS()

words = ["client relationships","people management","collaborative teams","collaborative team","collaboration teams"]
flags = [False] * len(words)
list1=[]
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    if flags[index]:
        continue
    t=set()
    for nested_index, nested_word in enumerate(words[index+1:]):
        if flags[nested_index + index]:
            continue
        v=metric_lcs.distance(word, nested_word)
        if v<=0.2:
            t.add(word)
            t.add(nested_word)
            flags[index] = True
            flags[nested_index + index] = True
    if t:
        list1.append(list(t))
```

And the output is:

```
[['collaborative team', 'collaborative teams', 'collaboration teams']]
```

Hope this helps.